# запуск .NET Core проекта через исполняемый (exe) файл

Tags: git, asp-net-core-mvc

Немного запутался.
Есть готовый `ASP.NET Core` проект. Хочу отправить его в репозиторий с возможностью запуска на локальной машине, например через .exe файл. Это делается через публикацию на `IIS`, или в виде службы Win, или как-то ещё?
Запустится ли исполняемый файл, если у склонированного репозитория не будет библиотек `.dll` (прописал это в gitignore)?

Comment: через iis - самое простое, только на iis нужно накатить .net core hosting bundle. для виндового сервиса нужен exe-файл, для веб-приложения - dll. дело в том, что dll, в отличии от exe, запускается внутри процесса родителя (в данном случае iis).